# How can I connect to SQL Server in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, sql-server, drupal-7, sqlsrv

I need to show some fields from another database (SQL Server), in my form in Drupal 7, but don't need disconnect from MySql.

I'm creating a custom module in Drupal 7 and in this module create connect to SQL Server, but this doesn't work, can anyone help me?

```
<?php

$serverName = "test"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"testdb", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"qwer");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
   echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
   echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: @Zhorov any errors. Now module do not enable, Im go to page.tpl.php and add this code there, F5 and me show white page, nth error